# String concatenation doesn't work in gawk print instruction

Tags: awk

I have the following grep and gawk line running in windows

```
grep ItemDischarged D:\systems\CmcComRouting.log | gawk -v OFS=, "{print $8}" | cut -d ">" -f 1 | uniq -c | gawk -v OFS=, "{print $1,$2}" > d:\03TotalItems.log
```

the **output** is as follows

```
59523,ItemDischargedTlg
```

What I want to do is add "Lower" to the end of "ItemDischargedTlg" but cannot figure out how to do it, I have tried

```
{print $1,$2"Lower"}
```

but it prints nothing.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html

Comment: Thanks, did read this and tried the suggestions but still prints nothing ?

Comment: Show us some input as well, pls.

Comment: Please mention your O.S details always, As far as I understood it looks Cygwin you are using, also let us know sample Input_file and expected output too so that we could help you more on same.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
gawk -v OFS=, '{$2=$2"Lower";print $1,$2}'
```

When trying to concatenate strings and commas you should be careful. Commas and concatenation as argument of a print instruction don't go well together.

If on windows, be careful with `"` and `'`.